# How to find index of array in a for loop

Tags: python

I am trying to find the index of a number that is greater than 10 but the next value is less than 10:

```
py =    np.array([    9.7,   10.1,   10.5,  10.2,  10.1,  9.9,   9.8])
```

So the answer should be 4. However, the output I got was 0. How do I fix the error?

```
for k in range(0,len(py)):
    if py[k]>10 and py[k+1]<10:
        position_y = np.argmax(k)
        print(position_y)
```

Comment: Your first number is 9.7 which is <10. So its False, for the next 4 numbers, it is greater than 10 but their successors are not, except the last one. Only `1 is the answer

Comment: You probably want to take a look at the [docs for `np.argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html). It's not clear what you expect it to do here. Really you can just `print(k)`

Comment: The ```numpy.argmax()``` function returns indices of the max element of the array in a particular axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
py = np.array([    9.7,   10.1,   10.5,  10.2,  10.1,  9.9,   9.8])

for index, value in enumerate(py):
    if value > 10 and py[index + 1] < 10:
        print(index)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(len(py)):
if (py[i]>10 and py[i+1]<10):
    print(i)
```